# Point z value Return 1.#QNAN while set before

Tags: python, arcgis-9.3

I am makin a python code for ArcGis 9.3. The code is as following :

```
rowsLine = gp.updatecursor(line_Feature_Class)
count = 0
rowLine = rowsLine.next()

rowsPoint = gp.InsertCursor(point_Feature_Class)
feat = rowsPoint.NewRow()


while rowLine:

#...

ptObj = gp.CreateObject('Point')
    ptObj.x = x1
    ptObj.y = y1
    ptObj.z = z1
    feat.Shape = ptObj
    rowsPoint.InsertRow(feat)

del rowsPoint

desc = gp.Describe(point_Feature_Class)
shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName

rowsAlti = gp.UpdateCursor(point_Feature_Class)
rowAlti = rowsAlti.Next()

while rowAlti :

    featAlti = rowAlti.GetValue(shapefieldname)
    pntAlti = featAlti.GetPart()
    Alti = pntAlti.z
    rowAlti.SetValue("Altitude", Alti)

    rowsAlti.updateRow(rowAlti)
    rowAlti = rowsAlti.Next()
```

The problem is that the return value of pntAlti.z is : 1.#QNAN. But if I replace pntAlti.z by pntAlti.x, then it works !

I saw that 1.QNAN means the value is not set. However I set the z value in my code : `ptObj.z = z1`

Thanks for your help

Comment: try with "del rowsPoint" after the InsertCursor loop

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this par of the code but actually it already exist. I will edit my post

Comment: I don't know if it can change anything but my point_Feature_Class is a shapefile (so not in a geodatabase).

Comment: May I have to use vertice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the full picture (where does z1 come from and is it valid ? Is your shapefile a 3D shapefile ?), but for a start the use of two cursors does not seem to be necessary.

```
while rowLine:
    #...
    feat = rowsPoint.NewRow()
    ptObj = gp.CreateObject('Point')
    ptObj.x = x1
    ptObj.y = y1
    ptObj.z = z1
    feat.Shape = ptObj
    feat.Altitude = z1
    rowsPoint.InsertRow(feat)
```

try to have a "print z1" in your loop to check  that z1 is OK.

also, make sure that your shp can store Z values (it is not the case by default)

[gp.CreateFeatureclass_management](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Create%5fFeature%5fClass%5f%28Data%5fManagement%29)(out_path, out_name, geometry_type, template, "DISABLED", "ENABLED", spatial_reference) #disabled has_M and enabled **has_Z**

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Your first solution works. I didn't know we could access the fiels by this way.               And I am sure that your second solution work also because my feature didn't take the Z value in account !   Thanks